# VLOOKUP all Rows and Return all Data

Tags: excel

I am using excel 2010. I am trying to do a VLOOKUP and retrieve all values. Here is my issue - I have data with medication frequency. The frequency is listed ones; but the frequency has more than one times. Example, freq BID (twice a day) has times 0900 and 1700. When I try to do VLOOKUP, it pulling in the first value only. How do I pull in all the values?

The function `=VLOOKUP(RC[-4],Sheet3!R5C1:R38C3,3,FALSE)` only pulls the first row it encounters. 
[image]

However, the associated FREQ has four times and notice its only pulling 00:00:00 in the above table.

[image]

Comment: I'm pretty sure that the whole purpose of a LookUp table is so that each row is a unique reference. There should only be one ID of 300825.  You may want to do some sort of Grouping of teh data prior to creating the look up table.

Comment: depends on what you want to do with the values after you pull them in (e.g. `COUNTIF` to count the # of occurrences, `SUMIF` to add all values meeting a given condition, `AVERAGEIF`, etc)... What do you want to do with the times that match the frequency?

Comment: Not so simple - like Jaycal says, depends what you want to do with the values.  There is no direct "pull all the values" approach - how would they all get in to one cell, concat, summation?  There are questions on here dealing with that.  Array formulas can sometimes be used, but usually only when quantity of occurrences is known.

Comment: You would be better off just placing it all in a pivot table, and drag the time value as a column item under the ID value.. then they would just line up automatically no matter how many exist for each.

Comment: Thank you all. I have to deal with this situation frequently. So thought there might be an easy way around. How do I close a question so its not out there?

Answer (score 0):

If `300285` for example represents every six hours starting at midnight then a LOOKUP function could be applied to return all four daily values at one time where these are in a single wrapped cell, such as:

```
 ="00:00:00"&CHAR(10)&"06:00:00"&CHAR(10)&"12:00:00"&CHAR(10)&"18:00:00"
```